# How to ask 'Is my own answer/solution to prev question correct'?

Tags: discussion

The day before I asked a question about [Ruby and I18N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658870/intercepting-i18n-translation-what-does-extend-module-new-do). It was viewed a few times and voted up once, but not answered.

Now after sleeping over that, I found a partial solution, which I *know* is correct; so I put it in question section with the edit: "found a partial answer".

And now, another "brain unscramble", I *think* I figured out my answer, but I am definitely not sure.

So how to go further?  What to do now?

Put the maybe answer in my question?

Answer my own question — but I am not sure if it is correct, getting downvoted, or never be informed that it is wrong?

Or ask a new question linked to the old one, and vice versa?

Or another solution?

Comment: +1 for posting here rather than just changing, wish more people would do the same

Comment: You might post your answer as an answer, and then add a comment along the lines of, “I haven’t tested this _exhaustively_; can anybody see any problems with it?” You should be notified of any other answers, or any other comments on either your question or your answer.

Comment: It seems to me that you're putting the horse before the cart. There's no pressure to answer your own question here now or tomorrow, or at all. Work through your solution and test it. Post a properly formed answer when you're ready.

Answer (score 11):

You should answer your own question -- which is what you have done.

Comment: I'd also note that it's not necessary to accept right away.  Some people who might have a better solution might not bother posting if OP has already accepted an answer.  It can be helpful, then, to post an answer in the hope of soliciting comments, or to provide a starting point for other answerers, but it might also make sense to wait a while before accepting it.

Comment: there was already a Answer here: "dont put an answer in a question", but this answer has been deteted here ...

Comment: @halfbit -- agree with don't answer by editing the question -- however that is not what you have done -- adding a partial answer in the question, highlighting it as additional information, amount to extra research which is good and constructive to getting a final answer.